# Error on modifying a contact in the address book (Ti.Contacts) >=iOS9

Tags: javascript, titanium, ios9, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Anyone here tried updating contact's info in the address book using `Ti.Contacts`?
`Ti.Contacts.save()` seems to be deprecated or is unresponsive in >=iOS9.

Here's a link related to the issue but I could still not find the right solution for updating a contact in the address book:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19002

Here's the code:

http://pastebin.com/92JafLqR

I get an error `NSContact setPhoneNumbers unrecognized selector sent instance on the targetContact['phone'] = phoneList;`  as well as for url, email and address.

Comment: The JIRA ticket is about implementing the new APIs and might have caused this bug, but could you please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/) and if it's not, create a ticket? Please link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: There actually is a JIRA ticket already: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20407

Comment: For those who need the same functionality, unfortunately custom labels will no longer be supported for iOS>=9. You can check the link @Fokke mentioned.